# How to copy a file with the same name from multiple directories into new directories using cp linux

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, unix, cp

I have multiple files with the same name in different directories
e.g.

```
path1/folder12345/file.zip
path1/folder74562/file.zip
path1/folder39842/file.zip
```

---

what I want is to copy every directory `folder*/file.zip` to a different location, but I only need file.zip inside the folders(each folder has multiple files inside) folder. How can I copy each parent directory with only file.txt inside to another location?

such that in the end I have something like

```
path1/folder39842/file.zip ---> path2/folder39842/file.zip
path1/folder74562/file.zip ---> path2/folder74562/file.zip
```

---

the trick is each `folder*` contains multiple files, I only need the one named `file.zip`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain the expected result. Where exactly and with what name do you want to have copies of the files `file.zip` from the different source directories.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin This should be an answer, it works, direct to the point, and taught me something aobut `cp` in the process :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `cp` from GNU coreutils, which is highly probable since the question is tagged with `linux`, then:

```
cd path1 && cp --parents folder*/file.zip ../path2
```